# Use Gulp to wrap javascript files with a IIFE

Tags: angularjs, gulp, iife

I have an angular app that has a lot of `.js` files.
It's boring to add an IIFE to each file and then add `'use strict'`.

Is there any way to automate this? I use gulp to run tasks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [the `gulp-wrap` plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-wrap/) with a simple template:

```
var wrap = require("gulp-wrap");

gulp.src("./src/*.js")
    .pipe(wrap('(function(){\n"use strict";\n<%= contents %>\n})();'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
```

This will wrap each file's contents with the template:

```
(function(){
"use strict";
//contents here…
})();
```

You can also store the template on the filesystem, rather than embedding it in your gulpfile, and call `gulp-wrap` using `wrap({src: 'path/to/template'})`

Comment: Good call. I skipped the newlines in the template to keep line numbers consistent when I get errors in the browser. My template was just `'(function(){ "use strict"; <%= contents %> })();'`

Comment: Note that there's also [`gulp-wrap-js` that claims](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-wrap-js) to be (contrary to `gulp-wrap`) compatible with `gulp-sourcemaps`.